# Open Layers 3: How to unbind a bindTo event on side-by-side maps?

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers-3

I am trying to unbind side-by-side maps in Open Layers 3 by building out from this example code on their official page:

http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/side-by-side.html

I would like to run a call to the page that unbinds the maps.  So far I tried using the "unbind" and "unbindAll" calls as documented here:

http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Object.html

I have tried each of the following calls and none have worked:

```
domMap.unbind('view');
domMap.unbindAll();

webglMap.unbind('view');
webglMap.unbindAll();

canvasMap.unbind('view');
canvasMap.unbindAll();
```

...are there any suggestions or alternatives I should try?

Comment: I see this functionality is labelled as experimental, though docs might be out of date. Looking at the source code on github, https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/object.js (line 248-250), and the example code, http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/side-by-side.js, it looks like the binding happens with the key, layergroup, so perhaps that is what you need to unbind.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your advice.  I tried to unbind the layergroup, but that did not work either...  Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, no. Sadly I'm not working on OpenLayers at the moment, so haven't had time to really investigate OL3 yet.

Answer (score 2):

The [side-by-side example](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/side-by-side.html) is a bit misleading.  The three maps there could share a view without the `bindTo` calls.

For example, here two maps share a single view:

```js
// one view shared by two maps
var view = new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 1
});

var map1 = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map1',
  view: view
});

var map2 = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map2',
  view: view
});
```

This is a much more straightforward way to "synchronize" two maps.  The difference is that if you use `bindTo` to bind the view property of one map to another, the view for both maps will be changed when you call `map.setView(newView)`.  The difference is subtle but important.  In both cases, you can have a single view shared by multiple maps.  If you call `bindTo`, when call `map.setView()` all maps with a bound view property are also updated.

So, if you wanted to give one of the maps in the side-by-side example a new view *without* giving them all a new view, you would first have to unbind the view property and then call `setView`.

```js
// give only the canvasMap a new view
canvasMap.unbind('view');
canvasMap.setView(new ol.View({center: [0, 0], zoom: 1}));
```

You should be able to confirm that after the `unbind` call, all maps still share the same view instance (e.g. `canvasMap.getView() === domMap.getView()`).